# How to integrate Parse + twitter in android app

Tags: android, twitter

Trying to integrate facebook and twitter in android app.here i am using parse.com .facebook login is completed with doc provided by parse.com.but felt difficlt with twitter integration ,is there any SDk for twitter.suggest any tutorial (easily understandable example) using parse not regular twitter tutorials.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think The tutorial in Parse it is the best tutorial about Twitter, What is your problem with Twitter? 
0. Create the app in Twitter 
1. Add compile `'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.+'` to your Gradle dependiencies
2. Put this in your Activity `ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("YOUR CONSUMER KEY", "YOUR CONSUMER SECRET");`
3. add This to your Twitter login button

```
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
    if (user == null) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
    } else if (user.isNew()) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
    } else {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
    }
  }
});
```

4. Enable in Parse the Twitter authentication in Settings section and it is all.

I had problems with ParseFacebookUtils but Twitter is easier and no I didn't find a good example on net about Twitter + Parse.